# How to Avoid multi post request by one click?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a simple form which adds personal information of a family. sometime it saves two instance of a person just by one submit. Maybe my mouse has problem and and double clicks instead of one click (it has some problems). I think this is not possible and django accepts just one post request from an instance of a form and not more (maybe it accepts). what if may code has problem? if it is problem of  my code, why it happens once a while?

```
 house = get_object_or_404(House, id=code)
 if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ParentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # save it if it's valid
        parent = form.save(commit=False)
        if parent.living == 0:
            parent.in_family = 0
        if not parent.guardian:
            parent.save()
        if parent.guardian and parent.in_family:
            parent.save()
```

I use Django 1.8

Edit to clear: this is not the only view sometime saves twice. Maybe it is a bug in django

Comment: Probably your view returns HttpRedirect to itself in any part of code?

Comment: No it is not. It goes somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, first you need to create unique constraint on the corresponding database table. The real solution is based on the database schema.  I don't know what fields (columns) you have in the `parent` table, you can start from add unique constraint to these two fields: `child_id` and `parent_name`.

The other problem is you need to prevent the second click. So basically you need to write some JavaScript code: it listens to the `onClick` event of the submit button. Once the button get clicked, the listener sets the `disabled` attribute to that button to prevent further clicks.